# From NodeJS Buffer to S3 file

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have a buffer returned by an API call containing file data however when I try to `S3.Upload()` or `fs.write()` the file is corrupt for anything except PDFs (png, jpg, .doc, .docx are the key types I need). For PDFs I just use the binary data as it comes in (`fs.writeFile('myFile.docx', myBuffer)`) but I've also tried:

- `fs.writeFile('myFile.docx', myBuffer.toString('base64'))`,
- `fs.writeFile('myFile.docx', myBuffer.toString('utf8'))`,
- `fs.writeFile('myFile.docx', myBuffer.toString('binary'))`

I'm sure it's to do with encoding the binary from the buffer but I've reached the limit of my knowledge with the above attempts.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that my method for dividing the data stream was leaving a trailing `/r/n` on the end of each file, PDFs don't seem to mind, everything else does.